# Selenium find by id doesn't work extranje access to the input

Tags: c#, selenium

I am doing screen scraping with selenium. there i have a problem,

I'm trying to access to an HTML input (by id), but c# told me that is not visible, but I can see it.

this is the c# exception:
`Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with`

but viewing this I tried to do with selenium extension of Firefox, and the command to access is strange.

[image]

how can I access to this input from my c# code?

thanks.

edit1: this is the HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="pxfirstname1" id="pxfirstname1" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
```

Also i checked on the CSS and doesn't have any hidden option.

Edit2: I tried to export to C#, but this is the result:

this is the code:

```
//code
driver.FindElement(By.Id("conSelC12")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("submitInfo")).Click();
// ERROR: Caught exception [Error: Dom locators are not implemented yet!]
// ERROR: Caught exception [Error: Dom locators are not implemented yet!]
driver.FindElement(By.Id("searchInf")).Click();
//more code
```

`// ERROR: Caught exception [Error: Dom locators are not implemented yet!]`

the other commands works fine

Comment: Provide generated C# as well please

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to export the code to C# from the plugin and then you can compare their suggested C# against your existing C# and see the problem or at least have working C# code

Comment: i tried this, but this is the result in the c# file `    // ERROR: Caught exception [Error: Dom locators are not implemented yet!]`

Comment: Wow, what does googling give you for that message? Sounds like it was developed in the Java version of Selenium but not yet in the C# version... just a guess

Comment: the solution in google is search the element by other way, like id, xpath, but i can't access it... dammit.